# "It's not a duplicate question" review process

Tags: support

I have a question that was marked as a duplicate:

[How can I find the list of all of vim's default keybindings?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8932/list-of-all-default-vim-keys)

I saw this text:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question.

So, I edited the question to explain how it is different and the edit went live.

How does someone get notified that this edit was about the supposed duplicate, rather than just an edit to improve the question?

How does the "Is it still a duplicate?" review process work from here?

Comment: [This help center article](http://vi.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions) may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry in slow response − I haven't been online much the last week.

> How does the original poster get notified about the review process decision?

I don't think you can. The entire review process is not very transparent.

In this question's case, it was reviewed in the "reopen queue" by five people, all of whom voted to leave it closed.

Asking a question in meta about this is the best course of action if you have a question. I think `@username` also works in comments if someone voted to close it, but I'm not 100% sure about this.

---

Onward to the question.

You added the note:

> the linked question is about the current mappings after based upon the user's configuration, while this question is about the default mappings before configuration.

But that is also what the linked question is about! It's not mentioned very explicitly, but judging from the accepted answer and the surrounding discussion I can be fairly sure that it is.

I have:

- Edited the linked question to make it clearer it's about the *default* mappings, and not user-defined mappings.
- Moved your *answer* to the linked question, as it's a good fit there.
- Upvoted your answer, as I didn't know this index help page existed :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and actions. It's amazing how text can "change" before a closer, slower re-reading :)

Answer (score 2):

Once you edit the question, it should appear in the reopen review queue automatically, and users with the appropriate reputation will be able to review it then.

Asking about it on meta, like you have (indirectly) is also a reasonable way to bring attention to the post.

Comment: How does the original poster get notified about the review process decision?

Comment: @TomHale Uh... you know, I don't know. I don't think I've ever had a question closed and reopened recently so I'm not sure if you get an inbox notification or not. You can always check manually though. With sufficient reputation you can see reopen vote counts (your question has two, currently).